# How do I store file uploads of a .Net core web application on Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

We are using GitHub Workflow to deploy a C# .Net Core web application on Azure. The web application consists of a file upload feature which stores file in the file system in local system during development, which saves the file in a child directory (`Documents`) of the `wwwroot` directory and is accessible to the client with a link for each file, eg. `/Documents/foo.pdf`

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as is on Azure after deployment.

After some research, I found that Azure file share is the way to go. How do I access the file stored in Azure file share from the web application with a link? Or if it is possible to store the file as in the local development, then how can it be done?

Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You should really use a native service like Azure Blob Storage for this use case. You can also access those files directly through a URL then.

Comment: Thanks. I shall try that. Also, I found that the issue was error in relative path in development as compared to on Azure.

Comment: Hi @BibekShah, I also have checked the the suggestion in my `@JasonPan`'s answer, and I think it's helpful. Have you tried it? Is it helpful to you? If it also helpful to you, I recommend that you can mark it as the solution of this topic. this may be also very helpful to more people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions.

Comment: The answer by @JasonPan is valid in certain scenario, but in my case, the folder was included and it was an issue in path while saving the file, due to which, it was being saved in a different path. So, I don't know if I should mark the answer as accepted, coz even though it is valid for some cases, in my case, it was a different error on my part.

Comment: Please check if your `foo.pdf` can be found in the scm website,

Comment: If possible, it is best to show us the screenshot of the file in kudu, and it is best to include the black window page of cmd.

Comment: I found it in a different location than I intended it to be that is, it was outside the wwwroot directory, so realized, I should change the path to be inside wwwroot directory. So, it was solved after finding that.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify `.csproj` file, then deploy your app.

I create `Html` folder, then deploy directly with no change in `.csproj` file.

I found no `Html` folder like below.

[image]

## Add below code in `.csproj` file.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="Html\**">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then deploy.

[image]